# How to solve: The currently activated Python version 3.9.2 is not supported by the project (~3.11). Trying to find and use a compatible version

Tags: tailwind-css, python-poetry

I want to run a Python project build with Python 3.11 , Django 4.1 and Tailwind CSS.
I followed rolling instructions: Prepare dev environment with Python 3.11 and poetry:

```
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
pyenv install 3.11.1
pyenv local 3.11.1
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
Install pre-commit from https://pre-commit.com/
Install dependencies with poetry install
Prepare DB with poetry run ./manage.py migrate
Prepare Tailwind with poetry run ./manage.py tailwind install
During dev, keep Tailwind compiler running in another tab: poetry run ./manage.py tailwind start
```

This was my last output:

```
Meltems-MBP:bieterverfahren-master meltem$ cd bieterverfahren/
Meltems-MBP:bieterverfahren meltem$ poetry run ./manage.py migrate
The currently activated Python version 3.9.2 is not supported by the project (~3.11).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3 (3.11.1)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Meltems-MBP:bieterverfahren meltem$ poetry run ./manage.py tailwind install
The currently activated Python version 3.9.2 is not supported by the project (~3.11).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3 (3.11.1)

up to date, audited 94 packages in 590ms

18 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Meltems-MBP:bieterverfahren meltem$ poetry run ./manage.py tailwind start
The currently activated Python version 3.9.2 is not supported by the project (~3.11).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3 (3.11.1)

> theme@3.4.0 start
> npm run dev


> theme@3.4.0 dev
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ../static/css/dist/styles.css -w


Rebuilding...

Done in 430ms.
```

What am I missing? Why am I still using Python version 3.9.2 instead of 3.11 ? How can I change it and how do I run the server with poetry/tailwind?

Answer (score 0):

just set your env to use the supported version

`poetry env use 3.11`